# responsive jquery image resizer

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have made the following code for an image re-size based of max width and same goes for height using `.height()`. The problem is still that I cannot find a good responsive image re-size plugin or something like that could re-size image when we re-size browser. Is there anything that can be implemented in my code or any new responsive plugin known to anyone to re-size image automatically when the browser is re-sized plus a default `max-width` and `height`?

my code for max width resize

```
// SET MIN AND MAX SIZE OF IMAGES
if (lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').width() > opt.maxWidth) {
    var oldimgw = lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').width();
    var oldimgh = lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').height();
    var perc = opt.maxWidth / oldimgw;
    lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').width(opt.maxWidth);
    lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').height(oldimgh*perc);
}

if (lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').width() < opt.minWidth) {
    var oldimgw = lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').width();
    var oldimgh = lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').height();
    var perc = opt.minWidth / oldimgw;
    lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').width(opt.minWidth);
    lboxitem.find('.tp-mainimage').height(oldimgh*perc);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.resize()` ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/resize/))

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AuJ5B/1/)

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var _width = $(window).width(),
        _height = $(window).height();

    // call your function() to make changes to its allowed maxes
});​
```

You might not even need Javascript for what you need... Think you can do what you need with CSS.

`img { width:100%; height:auto; min-width:300px; }`

Comment: can u explain it a little bit , i mean hw can i use it for specifically a image resize and with a max width and min width

Comment: Just updated the fiddle, resize the browser around. I think you can just use CSS to achieve that part once the images are out there already.

Comment: sry didnt see u used min-height for that . its working and what if i only want the image to be resized not the other things only the image

Comment: Only the image will be resized, jsFiddle just resizes that blue header on its own, but normally only the Image would. You need to just change the width of the `<div>` around the images and you'll be all set

Comment: will all the images in that page would be resized?

Comment: Well yes if you use a bland img { } style, specify yours to be for only images you want. #someDiv img... something like that